# preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes not called for supplementary views

Tags: ios8, autolayout, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I have a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` that makes use of the self-sizing mechanism in iOS 8. My `UICollectionViewCell`'s implement `preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes` to return their preferred size, calculated using auto-layout. This works fine.

However, I was expecting `preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes` to also work for supplementary views, but it is never called. It is defined on `UICollectionReusableView` after all.

If this mechanism is only for cells, what is the correct way to use auto-layout to size supplementary views in a custom `UICollectionViewLayout`?

Answer (score 3):

`preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes` will be called on supplementary views so long as they conform to the following requirements in your UICollectionViewLayout subclass (as far as I can tell!):

1. The supplementary view is laid out with a non-zero frame in `prepareLayout`
2. Layout attributes are provided for the supplementary view in  `layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:atIndexPath:`
3. The supplementary view is visible according to `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:`
4. Lastly, ensure the `elementKind` matches up in your CollectionView's `collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:` when the supplementary view is dequeued via `dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:forIndexPath:`

In summary: UICollectionViewLayout is a wicked beast but if tamed should be calling your supplementary view's `preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes`.

Comment: But the truth, surely, is that self-sizing cells don't really work very well, so one can't be surprised if self-sizing supplementary views don't work either.

Comment: They don't work very well but that doesn't mean the method shouldn't get called ;)